# A convergent improper integral is non-zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider a function $f(x):\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$. If the improper integral 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx
\end{align}
converges, will the value of this integral be non-zero?
Or are there examples of $f(x)$ with improper integral being zero. (except for $f(x)=0$ for all $x$)

Comment: Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ be your favorite series that converges to zero. Define
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n g(x - n),$$
where
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $0 \leq x < 1$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}\right)dx=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Take any $g$ for which the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} g(x)dx$ has some finite value $C$ and take $f(x)=g(x)-Ce^{-x}$. Examples of $g$ are plenty; for example $g(x)=e^{-ax}$ with $a>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example of an improper integral being zero:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^2+1}\,dx=0
\end{align}